# IN equivocalness of T-SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, t-sql

I have an IF condition,

```
IF (this.Something.GID == 1)
{
Something = "something";
}
```

I want to add one more option other than 1, I want to say

```
IF (this.Something.GID **is 1 or 2**)
{
Something = "something";
}
```

how do I go about doing that in C#?

Comment: There is no native way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (this.Something.GID == 1 || this.Something.GID == 2 )
{
 Something = "something";
}
```

It's better you start with some C# beginners book/tutorials.

Comment: I agree and I have started watching C%# beginners videos by Tom online. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could use an array and `Contains`:

```
var items = new int[] {1, 2};
if(items.Contains(this.something.GID))
{
}
```

If you execute the code locally (no O/R LINQ that is translated to SQL), a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) might perform better on big amounts of data:

```
var items = new HashSet<int>();
items.Add(1);
items.Add(2);
// equivalent one-liner, thanks to Eren
// var items = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2 }
if(items.Contains(this.something.GID))
{
}
```

If you know all elements at compile time, and they're of a `switch`-supporting type like `int` or `string`, you should go for Marc's approach with `switch`.

**On using `Contains`**

As I read in the comments, it may be helpful to explain my code a bit further. Basically, the code solves your problem **the other way round**: Rather than checking if `a` *is either* `b`, `c` *or* `d` it checks whether the collection `{b, c, d}` **contains** `a` (which is *equivalent*).

**On arrays and `HashSet`**

An array and a `HashSet` are two different implementations that are useful for this problem. In general, you can find elements in a `HashSet` *faster* than in an array.

An array performs *linear search*, which is iterating over *each element* and checking whether it is the wanted element (effort is **linear** to the length of the array). A `HashSet` stored elements in an array too. However, when you search for an element, it computes an *integer hash* out of the wanted element and checks whether *the single element* at `hash % array_length` in its inner array is the wanted element (**constant** effort).

You may check out the Wikipedia articla on [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for further details (quite a bit of reading, but very interesting).

Comment: In a tight loop I have seen performance gains in lists as small as 5 items by using a `HashSet`. I had to filter out non printable characters in a stream before a XmlReader handled the stream and switching from a `List<char>` of 5 items to a `HashSet<char>` of 5 items took the processing time of the file from 5 minutes to 20 seconds.

Comment: also note that you can use the collection initializer: `new HashSet<int> { 1, 2 }`.

Comment: Of course, whatever structure you use, implement it once outside the flow of the code so it only needs to be constructed once and called many times.

Comment: Umm...that's bit advanced for me but I will definitely try to understand what is going on in your code..it might come in handy in future.

Comment: @user1569220 It comes at it from the other side.  Took me a minute to figure it out also.  +1

Comment: @user1569220 I appreciate your feedback. I added further information about the theory behind my solution (to help you whenever you need the code or have time to spend a little time on reading). I hope I expressed myself comprehensibly.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
like this:

```
switch (this.Something.GID)
{
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3: 
      Something = "something";
  break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have used the other solution. Your's will definitely come in handy sometimes in future.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `||` and `&&` on this.

```
if ((this.Something.GID == 1) || (this.Something.GID == 2))
{
     Something = "something";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was doing this.Something.GID == 1 || 2 instead of what you proposed, which is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( (new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}).Any(x => x == 3) )
{
    Something = "...";
```